# How to resolve ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

Here's a sample of the column of my dataset on which I am working now:

```
print (data)
     Credit Days
0             30
1   Cash & Carry
2   Cash & Carry
3             20
4             20
5             30
6             15
7             10
8             15
9   Cash & Carry
10            10
11            10
12            21
13  Cash & Carry
14            20
15            20
```

So this column contains both string and integer values. I have to convert these values to integer ratings and have to save them to a newly created column,say, credit_days_rating. For that I wrote a code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', engine='python')

data['Credit Days'].astype(str)
if data['Credit Days']=='Cash & Carry':
    data['credit_days_rating'] = 4
else :
    data['Credit Days'].astype(int)
    if (data['Credit Days']>= 10) & (data['Credit Days']< 19):
        data['credit_days_rating'] = 3
    elif (data['Credit Days']>= 20) & (data['Credit Days']< 29):
        data['credit_days_rating'] = 2 
    else :
        data['credit_days_rating'] = 1
```

For that I am getting the following error log:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-f6ecf070a2d4> in <module>()
      2 
      3 data['Credit Days'].astype(str)
----> 4 if (data['Credit Days']=='Cash & Carry'):
      5     data['credit_days_rating'] = 5
      6 else :

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1119         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1120                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
-> 1121                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1122 
   1123     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

the new column should look like this:

[image]

Comment: `if [1, 2 3] == 2`. How would you answer that?

Comment: What is expected output from data? What happen outside `(data['Credit Days']>= 10) & (data['Credit Days']< 19)` ?

Comment: @jezrael I updated. Plz check.

Comment: What are another conditions for rating?

Comment: @roganjosh : I updated the code to list all conditions. plz check.

Comment: @jezrael : I updated the code to list all conditions. plz check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for set values by list of conditions, for compare numeric values use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for converting non numeric to `NaN`s:

```
m1 = data['Credit Days']=='Cash & Carry'

s = pd.to_numeric(data['Credit Days'], errors='coerce')
m2 = (s>= 10) & (s< 19)
m3 = (s>= 20) & (s< 29)
masks = [m1,m2,m3]
vals = [4,3,2]
data['credit_days_rating'] = np.select(masks, vals, default=1)
print (data)
     Credit Days  credit_days_rating
0             30                   1
1   Cash & Carry                   4
2   Cash & Carry                   4
3             20                   2
4             20                   2
5             30                   1
6             15                   3
7             10                   3
8             15                   3
9   Cash & Carry                   4
10            10                   3
11            10                   3
12            21                   2
13  Cash & Carry                   4
14            20                   2
15            20                   2
```

Answer (score 1):

this is one way to do it. Using coerce to set strings to NaN

```
s = pd.Series([21,'Cash & Carry',10,20])

df = pd.DataFrame(s,columns=['Credit Days'])
df["credit_days_rating"] = 'NaN'
df.loc[df['Credit Days'] == 'Cash & Carry', 'credit_days_rating'] = 5
df.loc[(pd.to_numeric(df['Credit Days'], errors='coerce') >= 10) & (pd.to_numeric(df['Credit Days'], errors='coerce') < 19),'credit_days_rating'] = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you want is actually to apply a function over your column to get some column that is only integer type.  This can be done in the following way:

```
data = ["some str", 10, 20, "some str", 1, 2, 3]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def my_function(value):
    if value == "some str":
        return 5
    elif value >= 10 or value < 19:
        return 3

df['new_col'] = df[0].apply(my_function)

df
```

The output is then:

```
    0          new_col
0   some str    5
1   10          3
2   20          3
3   some str    5
4   1           3
5   2           3
6   3           3
```

What (data['Credit Days']=='Cash & Carry') is doing is returning a pandas Series instance of boolean values, for instance:

```
df[0] == "some str"

0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

If you want one boolean instead, for use in a conditional statement, you will want to use the Series internal method all() or any():

```
(df[0] == "some str").any()

True
```

Comment: If you're going to do it this way, use `np.where`